# MacBook Pro Ethernet drivers for Ubuntu. How to install?

Tags: networking, drivers, ubuntu-10.04, macbook-pro

I have installed Ubuntu 10.04 TLS - the Lycid Lynx onto MacBook Pro ([specs](http://www.everymac.com/systems/apple/macbook_pro/stats/macbook-pro-core-i7-2.66-aluminum-15-mid-2010-unibody-specs.html)). I have used it so far with wireless network and everything was fine until I have tried using wired network - it does not even seem to notice that I have plugged cable in.

I am no expert in Ubuntu hardware configuration and thus don't know what kind of information is needed to track the problem down and/or fix it. Please, feel free to request more information from me, but tell me explicitly what I am supposed to do (e.g. which commands to run, which config files to edit).

Thank you.

**EDIT:** Adding device info from `lspci`:

```
$ lspci -nn | grep -i gigabi
02:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Broadcom Corporation NetXtreme BCM5764M Gigabit Ethernet PCIe [14e4:1684] (rev 10)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turned out that it was silly me. All I needed was to click on "Auto eth0" in the wired network list. For some reason, despite it's name it does not connect automatically until you click it for the first time manually.

Answer (score 1):

The first thing to do is identify the vendor and product IDs via `lspci -nn` (they will be the pair of 4 hex digit values at the end). From there you can identify which driver it uses, and then follow the directions that come with it to build it for your kernel.

Comment: Thank you. I've edited the question and added output for lspci.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to previous answers and chatGPT I was able to enable Thunderbolt ethernet on a MacBookPro Retina early 2013 with a fresh installation of Ubuntu Server 22.04.3.

Steps taken:

```
ip link
```

Note the interface name that has something like  <BROADCAST, MULTICAST> (in my case it was called enp13s0)

```
sudo nano /etc/netplan/01-netcfg.yaml
```

Enter:

```
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: networkd
  ethernets:
    <your interface name>:
      dhcp4: true
```

Followed by commands

```
sudo netplan apply
sudo systemctl restart systemd-networkd
sudo systemctl restart systemd-resolved
```

And then to verify

```
ping -c 4 google.com
```